# How to use property()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble on how to implement property to protect attributes.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def set_x(self, x):
        if '_x' in dir(self):
            raise NotImplementedError("Cannot change x coordinate")
        else:
            self._x = x

    def get_x(self):
        return self._x

    #I beleive my mistake is here. I'm not sure if I'm implementing this correctly
    x = property(get_x, set_x, None, None)
```

So  I want to prevent any user from changing the x-coordinate. My question is, how do I get python to redirect the user to the set_x() and get_x() methods? I've tried running this code in terminal and whenever I apply the following, the point changes.

```
p = point(3, 4)
p.x = 5 #x is now 5
```

Comment: Are you running on python3.x?  If not, make sure that you inherit from `object`.

Comment: Also note that you'll get yourself into an infinite loop in `get_x` since `get_x` has the line `return self.x` which will call `get_x`, which has the line `return self.x` ... You probably want to return `self._x` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works on both python2.x and python3.x:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def set_x(self, x):
        if '_x' in dir(self):
            raise NotImplementedError("Cannot change x coordinate")
        else:
            self._x = x

    def get_x(self):
        return self._x

    x = property(get_x, set_x, None, None)

p = Point(2, 3)
print(p.x)  # 2
p.x = 6  # NotImplementedError
```

Pretty much all I did was inherit from `object` (to get it to work on python2.x) and use the name `Point` rather than `point` (which would have been a `NameError` before).

There are other things you can do to clean it up a bit (e.g. khelwood's suggestion of just writing the getter -- or DSM's suggestion of using `hasattr` instead of `'_x' in dir(self)`).

---

Note, if you really just want a type that takes an `x` and `y` arguments that you want to be immutable -- Maybe you should consider using a `colledctions.namedtuple`

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x,y')
p = Point(2, 3)
p.x  # 2
p.y  # 3
p.x = 6  # AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: Yes. `namedtuple`. Good idea.

Comment: @DSM -- I'd rather forget that implementation entirely and used a `namedtuple` :-)

Comment: @mgilson: even better!

Answer (score 5):

You only need this much:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self.y = y
    def get_x(self):
        return self._x
    x = property(get_x)
```

You can set the hidden field `self._x` in your `init`, then you don't need a setter for `x` at all. And have `get_x` return `self._x` rather than `self.x` so it doesn't try and call itself.

You can use the `@property` decorator to do this even more succinctly.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self.y = y
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
```